# Why can't I butcher dead chinchillas?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So my hunterdwarf has been out in the field, and he's killed and hauled back some chinchilla corpses to my butcher shop. The only problem is that when the corpses are placed in the butcher shop neither does it trigger an automatic butcher animal job, nor will it let me manually assign the job. If I manually assign it'll just give the announcement:

> Blah blah, Farmer cancels butcher an animal: Needs butcherable nearby unrotten item.

As far as I can tell from the wiki etc. any animal that my hunters kill should be butcherable, so I have no idea why it wont let my dwarfs feast on delicious small furry animals.

Screenshot of butcher shop:

[image: Just left of center!]

Comment: Did you try skinning and tanning the cincilla? Sound like a more sensible option with that kind of critter...;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chincillas are small.

So small, in fact, that butchering them will yield no meat at all.

The Dwarven Butcher realizes this, and decides that butchering the corpse for no meat isn't worth the effort, and simply ignores it.

Essentially, your dwarves are lazy, but in this case, they're actually being productively lazy instead of uselessly lazy (wasting time butchering things for no return).

Comment: Rabbits and some of the new non-vermin birds are like this too.

Comment: So basically my hunterdwarf is just out there killing small furry animals for fun?

Comment: @BigStuuu Yup. They'll hunt skeletal wildlife too, despite the fact that those guys don't butcher to meat, either.

Comment: Bones are great though.

Comment: Butchers will butcher creatures as long as they produce anything other than a skull (which all creatures produce, and they're useless). It's not just meat; they're happy to butcher skeletons for only bones if the skeleton is large enough. Chinchillas aren't though.

Comment: @PaulZ I'm pretty sure you can make totems out of skulls, which you can then place in a public area for happiness or sell.

Comment: @SaintWacko Yeah, but that's how it works. If it'll give a skull and nothing else, no butchering. What's available depends on creature size.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Right, I was just pointing out that skulls aren't useless. Can't wait til this next update. Dwarves riding minecarts! :D

Comment: @SaintWacko Well, sure. You can make (useless) finished goods called totems out of skulls. You can't actually build totems as decorations (you can arrange for them to be stockpiled in pleasing locations, but dwarves don't care), and dwarves don't claim them as belongings, so they're just trade goods. And they're worth the same as things which are much easier to make in bulk. The only point of totems is that they are the only thing you can do with skulls, but butchering a creature JUST for its skull is a giant waste of time.